# Representing variable object arrays in JSON

Tags: json

Is there a way to represent an object array in JSON? e.g. Supposing I have the server-side method `Test(object[])` which expects any of the three following classes:

```
class ObjectA{ int a; }
class ObjectB{ bool a; }
class ObjectC{ string a; }
```

What would `new object[]{ new ObjectA(), new ObjectB(), new ObjectC() }` look like when represented in JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it would be:

```
[{"a": 42}, {"a": true}, {"a": "The answer is"}]
```

The only way to preserve the *type* of object, would be to add an additional property. JSON does not know anything about *classes*. There are only objects which have certain properties.

Comment: No, that means that JSON does not have any object types. The only types in JSON are arrays, objects, strings, numbers, booleans and null.

Comment: Woops, I deleted my comment before realizing you had already replied. Either way, thanks for the clarification. I'm going to add a common "typename" property to all objects, which the server can then inspect to determine what other properties it holds.